# mvcScaffolding / EF Code First creates column for related table as though to insert the related table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, scaffolding

Hi i am using MVCScaffolding, with MySQL  its a bit of a pain but i have this:

```
public class SubCategories
{
    [Key, Display(Name = "ID"), HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false), Required]
    public Int32 SubCategoriesId { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string SubCategoriesName { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool SubCategoriesShow { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Category")]
    public Int32 CategoriesId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Categories
{
    [Key, Display(Name = "ID"), HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false), Required]
    public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool CategoryShow { get; set; }
}
```

this is great and when i add a sub category, it creates a dropdwon of categories, but it also creates the column Category_CategoriesId   this i dont want, i have tried to set scaffolding to false but this doesent seem to work eith

help very much appreciated

thanks

Comment: sory Adding [ForeignKey("CategoriesId")]   to my virtial Categories in Sub Categories fixes this, post back my answer as an answer and i will mark as resolved.  also  anyone know property in the T4 template to set the column names on generated tables ????  tried ShortName but this did not work  T4  Says <th>
            <#= property.Name #>
        </th>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, what about [Column("name")]?
I tought about adding [Editable(false)] for what you have already solved.

to help you close it

Adding [ForeignKey("CategoriesId")] to virtual Categories in Sub Categories fixes it.

Comment: column name not work its just not built into mvcscaffolding but thanks :-)